# Monitoring Azure Functions Container Instances and fetching meta data

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to monitor Azure Functions instances.

1. Is there an event invoked when Azure Functions creates/destroys a new instance due to load? I would like Azure to notify me upon creation or destruction of Function instances.
2. Where can I see container instances list and their meta data (instance id, ip, etc)?
3. Is there an 'enrollment' event raised after a new instance is created?
4. When I use SCM, which instance am I controlling?

Thanks!